# SQL query print two columns from two tables with count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I have a table with recipies and one with ingredients, and one that connects them.

How can I make a query that lists each recipe and the number of ingredients there are in each one?

I have tried using count but I find it hard to work since we are getting data from two tables and have to print two things.
Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE recipe(
id INTEGER,
title TEXT,
time INTEGER,
difficulty INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE ingredient(
id INTEGER,
name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE ingredient_recipe(
id_ingredient INTEGER,
id_recipe INTEGER
);
```

Edit: I know how to just print out all the counts, but I have no idea how to proceed from this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ingredient_recipe
GROUP BY id_recipe
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.  At a minimum, you should show your attempt.

Comment: @crimson589 It's a many-to-many relationship, an ingredient can be used in more than one recipe.

Comment: This is the worst advice as one ingredient (onion for example) can be in multiple recipes.

Comment: @Barmar ah, may bad that didn't cross my mind.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the hints. I added a small piece of code. But I literally have no idea of how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is halfway there. You just need to bring in the `recipe` table with a `join`:

```
SELECT ir.id_recipe, r.title, COUNT(*) cnt_ingredients
FROM ingredient_recipe ir
INNER JOIN recipe r ON r.id = ir.id_recipe
GROUP BY ir.id_recipe, r.title
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need:   SELECT COUNT(*) qty, recipe.name as recipe FROM ingredient_recipe ir inner join recipe on recipe.id = ir.id_recipe GROUP BY ir.id_recipe;  It is a very basic sql query. You need to read a mysql tutorial.

Comment: I think so too.